# How to assign groups based on sum of values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

If I have two columns as below, I would like to put records in buckets such that total sum is less then 500. Individual input record count will never be more then 500. I would like to achieve with out using PL/SQL functions

```
id   | bundle_count                     id   |  bundle_count| group_id
-----|---------                         -----|--------------|--------
1    | 330                              1    | 330          | 1
2    | 150                              2    | 150          | 1
3    | 200          =============>      3    | 200          | 2
4    | 280          Desired output      4    | 280          | 2
5    | 200          =============>      5    | 200          | 3
```

Comment: Should the ids be ordered?  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Order of the ids are not important. Just need to assign into different buckets. I'm using Oracle 18c

Comment: . . That makes this a bin-packing problem which is quite hard to implement.

Comment: What if there were a row with `id` = 6 and a `bundle_count` = 15?  Should that get added to `group_id` = 1, since there is still room for 15 more in that group?  Or should it be added to `group_id` = 3, because we are processing the rows in order?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - can be added to any bucket, placing into different buckets is the requirement as along as the sum is under 500.

Comment: Very good question +1. I added an answer that works in PostgreSQL. I think there may be another option for Oracle using nested Recursive CTEs. I'll give it a try tomorrow, since it's late now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to solve using below query

```
SELECT id, bundle_count, ceil(sum(bundle_count) over(order by id) /500) as group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: this is not a good answer since it doesn't work in Oracle**

This solution works in PostgreSQL and does not require the `ID`s to be sequential. Unfortunately, it does not work in Oracle, since Oracle places a few restrictions on Recursive CTEs; it doesn't allow `LIMIT` in the iterative member of the Recursive CTE.

I wanted to show how you can cleanly do it in PostgreSQL. Here it is:

```
with recursive
x as (
  select id, bundle_count, bundle_count as s, 1 as grp from t where id = 1
 union all (
  select t.id, t.bundle_count, 
    case when x.s + t.bundle_count < 500 then x.s + t.bundle_count
                                         else t.bundle_count end,
    case when x.s + t.bundle_count < 500 then x.grp else x.grp + 1 end
  from t 
  join x on t.id > x.id 
  order by id
  limit 1
  )
)
select * from x order by id
```

Result:

```
id  bundle_count    s  grp
--  ------------  ---  ---
 1           330  330    1
 2           150  480    1
 3           200  200    2
 4           280  480    2
 5           200  200    3
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5cMrDj6ETARz8sDPftNmhD/0).

Answer (score 0):

If the `ID`s are sequential, then you can do it in Oracle as shown below:

```
with
x (id, bundle_count, s, grp) as (
  select id, bundle_count, bundle_count, 1 from t where id = 1
 union all (
  select t.id, t.bundle_count, 
    case when x.s + t.bundle_count < 500 then x.s + t.bundle_count 
                                         else t.bundle_count end,
    case when x.s + t.bundle_count < 500 then x.grp else x.grp + 1 end
  from t 
  join x on t.id = x.id + 1
  )
)
select * from x order by id;
```

Result:

```
id  bundle_count    s  grp
--  ------------  ---  ---
 1           330  330    1
 2           150  480    1
 3           200  200    2
 4           280  480    2
 5           200  200    3
```

See running example at [SQL<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5fa71045eb5bf0ed19a34bef1880c19).

If they are not sequential, then the nested recursive CTE is the option to use.